# why is the type of a tuple a list when only one list is present inside the tuple?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

x=([1,2,3])

**type(x)= List**

x=([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

**type(x)=tuple**

why does the type change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for creating a tuple with only one item is to follow the item with a comma:

```
x=([1,2,3],)
```

which for this example will in fact give

```
type(x)=tuple
```

Reference the [official Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

which states (quote)

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).